# How can I create a php mail handler for a dynamically created form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am creating a form builder plugin for wordpress allowing users to build their own custom forms.

I have managed to design the form builder, now I am looking at the form submit handler. I'm using a php handler, something similar to this:

```
<?php
// process.php

$errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors
$data           = array();      // array to pass back data

// validate the variables ======================================================
// if any of these variables don't exist, add an error to our $errors array

if (empty($_POST['name']))
    $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';

if (empty($_POST['email']))
    $errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';

if (empty($_POST['superheroAlias']))
    $errors['superheroAlias'] = 'Superhero alias is required.';

// return a response ===========================================================

// if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false
if ( ! empty($errors)) {

    // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
} else {

    // if there are no errors process our form, then return a message

    // DO ALL YOUR FORM PROCESSING HERE
    // THIS CAN BE WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO (LOGIN, SAVE, UPDATE, WHATEVER)

    // show a message of success and provide a true success variable
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Success!';
}

// return all our data to an AJAX call
echo json_encode($data);
```

However, as mentioned, my forms are created dynamically, so I can't use hard coded variables.

I'm not sure of a good way forward with this, can anyone suggest a way I can use the dynamically created variables in my main form builder file as part of this handler file?

Here is my php builder code:

```
<form action="./includes/process.php" method="POST">
                    <?php foreach ( wp_parse_id_list( $widget[ 'form_builder_ids' ] ) as $form_builder_key ) {

....

<div class="media-body <?php echo ( isset( $item['design']['fonts'][ 'align' ] ) ) ? $item['design']['fonts'][ 'align' ] : ''; ?>">
                                            <?php if( $this->check_and_return( $item, 'label') ) { ?>
                                                <label>
                                                    <?php echo $item['label']; ?>
                                                        <?php if( $this->check_and_return( $item, 'required') ) { ?>
                                                            <span class="required" style="color:#c0392b;">*</span>
                                                        <?php } ?>
                                                </label>
                                            <?php } ?>

                                            <?php if( $this->check_and_return( $item, 'input_type') ) { ?>

                                            <?php
                                                $input_type_array = array('select', 'textarea', 'checkbox', 'radio');
                                                if( !in_array( $item['input_type'] ,$input_type_array ) ) {?>
                                                    <input type="<?php echo $item['input_type']; ?>" name="<?php echo $item['input_name']; ?>" <?php if( $this->check_and_return( $item, 'required') ) { echo 'required'; } ?>>

                                                <?php } else if ($item['input_type'] == 'textarea') { ?>
                                                    <textarea name="<?php echo $item['input_name']; ?>" <?php if( $this->check_and_return( $item, 'required') ) { echo 'required'; } ?>></textarea>

                                                <?php } else if ($item['input_type'] == 'select') { ?>
                                                    <select name="<?php echo $item['input_name']; ?>" <?php if( $this->check_and_return( $item, 'required') ) { echo 'required'; } ?>>
                                                        <?php foreach(explode("\n", $item['select_options']) as $select_option) { ?>
                                                            <option value="<?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/','', $select_option); ?>"><?php echo $select_option; ?></option>
                                                        <?php } ?>
                                                    </select>

                                                <?php } else if ($item['input_type'] == 'checkbox') { ?>
                                                        <?php foreach(explode("\n", $item['select_options']) as $select_option) { ?>
                                                            <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $item['input_name']; ?>" value="<?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/','', $select_option); ?>" <?php if( $this->check_and_return( $item, 'required') ) { echo 'required'; } ?>><?php echo $select_option; ?>
                                                        <?php } ?>


                                                <?php } else if ($item['input_type'] == 'radio') { ?>
                                                        <?php foreach(explode("\n", $item['select_options']) as $select_option) { ?>
                                                            <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $item['input_name']; ?>" value="<?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/','', $select_option); ?>" <?php if( $this->check_and_return( $item, 'required') ) { echo 'required'; } ?>><?php echo $select_option; ?>
                                                        <?php } ?>


                                                <?php } ?>
                                            <?php } ?>

                                    </div>

....
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add a static `id` to the form elements and then process it with ajax/js?

Comment: @OliverQueen not really as there is the possibility that users may add more than one form to the page

Comment: Do you have control over the HTML content in the forms?

Comment: @OliverQueen I think so yes - I'm basically writing this plugin from scratch, so can change most things at this point

Comment: Okay, I have an idea, I'm going to write my suggestion in an answer

Answer (score 1):

I'd achieve something like this by setting an incremental javascript global var:

```
var x = 0;


function addForm(){
    var formHTML = '<form onsubmit = "submitForm(' + x + '); return false;"> <input id = "name' + x + '" ...  </form>';
    x = x+1;
}

function submitForm(formIdentifier){
    var name = document.getElementById("name"+formIdentifier).value; //how you can get the form values from dynamic forms
    //process form with ajax from here
}
```

Where `addForm()` is that code that would add the form to the page, and `submitForm` is where you would process the data from a dynamic form submit event.

Let me know if you need some more clarification.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think it will point me in the right direction. The issue I'm facing is that users can create totally unique forms (including the names for all the inputs). So for example, user A could create <input type="text" name="first_name">... whilst user B could create <input type="checkbox" name="some_name" value="yes"> So obviously my issue here is trying to capture the uniqueness of each form, and parse that through my handler - not sure if your script allows me to do this?

Comment: If it helps, let me quickly add my form builder php code - not sure how much sense it will make out of context though

Comment: I would suggest setting a blank div somewhere that you populate with other divs that contains a list of names (separated by a comma), which you can then use the form identifier to grab the specific div with the names of that form, then separate them with the `split()` javascript function

Comment: Not a bad idea actually, do you think I could get away with it being a hidden input

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd do

Comment: I'll give it a shot and see what I come up with, thanks

Comment: @SamSkirrow - no problem, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I had to take a break from this last night, was getting confusing. I have managed to add a hidden field to my form that returns the form contents in this format INPUT-TYPE:INPUT-NAME, INPUT2-TYPE:INPUT2-NAME, etc. However, I'm not sure where to go from here, or even if there is a different approach to use?? I've started to think I might need a developer on this...you free?

Comment: @SamSkirrow - sorry I just saw this. Yes I am